# Oracle Query that needs optimization due to date filter making it run slow

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization

I have a query that needs to be optimized and help is needed. The query takes an unacceptable amount of time to complete.

Here is the generic form of the query (UPDATED FROM EARLIER):

```
WITH

    SQ_Filter_Date AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            Business_Day AS Filter_Business_Day
        FROM
            Table_A
        WHERE
            Load_Date BETWEEN TO_DATE( '2019-11-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) AND TO_DATE( '2019-12-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' )
    ),

    SQ_Table_A_Results AS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            Table_A sr INNER JOIN SQ_Filter_Date sfd ON ( sr.Business_Day = sfd.Filter_Business_Day )
    ),

    SQ_Final AS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
            SQ_Table_A_Results a 
            JOIN Table_B b ON ( a.A_Source_Key = b.B_Source_Key )
            JOIN Table_C c ON ( a.A_Type_Key = c.C_Type_Key )
            JOIN Table_D d ON ( a.A_Business_Type_Key = d.D_Business_Type_Key )
    )

SELECT *
FROM
    SQ_Final
```

Table_A has an index column that is the primary key. Table_A is also partitioned by Business_Day. So if we filter on Business_Day then no problem. The issue is that we need to filter on an un-indexed column called Load_Date. I have checked and we are not allowed to add an index to that column due to things outside of my control.

So how can this query be modified to run faster?

Comment: "I checked and it is not an option to create an index on Load_Date." -- What does that mean? You cannot add indexes? If so, why?

Comment: How do you know that it's the date filters that are causing slowness, and not the joins? Here is one way you may be able to tell, one way or the other. Select just the data from table_A, with the date filters on it (no joins). Is that slow also? If not, then your guess is probably wrong. One way or the other, this will let you focus on what is really slow. No need to mix up the joins with the date filters on a single table in the same optimization question.

Comment: Are the values you JOIN ON **unique**?

Comment: @stickybit, the dba has informed me that we cannot add another index. So unfortunately it is not an option and I cannot change that.

Comment: @mathguy, you are right. I tried what you said and the problem is with the join on the column with Table_D. But that join is needed for the correct result set. So how can I fix that?

Comment: @PM77-1, this is a stand join. What do you mean by: "Are the values you JOIN ON unique?"  ?

Comment: I was wondering whether you are creating a partial Cartesian product in your joins.

Comment: @PM77-1, if that was the case then how can I adjust the query to fix a partial Cartesian product?

Comment: It is impossible to answer not knowing the type of relationship between A and other tables. Also make sure that you join on indexed fields.

Comment: @PM77-1, there is a primary key to foreign key relationship between the tables, as shown in the code in the question.Yes, indexed fields are being used. The problem is with the Load_Date as per the question above.

Comment: You previously posted: "the problem is with the join on the column with Table_D".  this is what I was commenting about.  Is that no longer the case?

Comment: The problem is actually with the date filter. Why? Because it has no index and filtering with it takes very long. It's not an option to create an index on that column due to reasons outside of my control.

Comment: Another point, why are you doing the 2 first SQL of the WITH clause? If seems to me that the join between TABLE_A and SQ_Filter_Date is useless, why not just add a filter on LOAD_DATE to SQL_Final? This may not speed up your query a lot, but it makes much simpler to see where you're loosing time (i.e. Reading TABLE_A, or joining , ....)

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
WITH 
SQ_Filter_Date AS
(
    SELECT 
        A_Business_Type_Key, 
        MIN(LOAD_DATE) as MIN_LOAD_DATE,
        MAX(LOAD_DATE) as MAX_LOAD_DATE
    FROM
        Table_A
    GROUP BY
        A_Business_Type_Key

),
SQ_Table_A_Results AS
(
    SELECT A_Business_Type_Key
    FROM
        SQ_Filter_Date
    WHERE
    *-- << 
    --   have the date check here - 
    --   i dont whether this check is complete 
    --   so change it according to your needs 
    -- >>* 
    MIN_LOAD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE( '2019-11-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) AND TO_DATE( '2019-12-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' )
    or MAX_LOAD_DATE BETWEEN TO_DATE( '2019-11-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) AND TO_DATE( '2019-12-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' )
    
),
SQ_Final AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM
        SQ_Table_A_Results a 
        JOIN Table_B b ON ( a.A_Source_Key = b.B_Source_Key )
        JOIN Table_C c ON ( a.A_Type_Key = c.C_Type_Key )
        JOIN Table_D d ON ( a.A_Business_Type_Key = d.D_Business_Type_Key )
)

SELECT * FROM SQ_Final
```

Comment: I don't think this is functionally equivalent as `between` will include 'holes' in `Business_Day `

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid a (possibly) expensive `DISTINCT` with this, but no idea if it will be any faster without any idea on cardinality and indexes

```
WITH
    SQ_Table_A_Results AS
    (
        SELECT *
        FROM
        Table_A sr 
        WHERE EXISTS (
             SELECT * FROM Table_A F
             WHERE F.Load_Date BETWEEN 
             TO_DATE( '2019-11-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) 
             AND 
             TO_DATE( '2019-12-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' )
             AND F.Business_Day  = sr.Business_Day
        )

SELECT *
FROM
    SQ_Table_A_Results a 
    JOIN Table_B b ON ( a.A_Source_Key = b.B_Source_Key )
    JOIN Table_C c ON ( a.A_Type_Key = c.C_Type_Key )
    JOIN Table_D d ON ( a.A_Business_Type_Key = d.D_Business_Type_Key )
```

You'll also have less columns